# Runnning subpackages of python-3.4 astropy-0.3 library on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python

I have successfully installed astropy-0.3 with python-3.4 on ubuntu-14.04 but whenever I search any conventional library of astropy like **cosmology, time, units** it doesn't work here.. Is this library specifically made for windows or any thing else?

I am using astropy library on IDLE python-2.7 conveniently in windows 7.

Any help regarding this issue??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the terminal run:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-astropy
```

Now to check if it is working open IDLE3 and run the following commands in IDLE3:

```
import astropy
from astropy.cosmology import WMAP9 as cosmo
dir(astropy)
```

The expected output of `dir(astropy)` is:

```
['ConfigurationItem', 'UNICODE_OUTPUT', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__githash__', '__loader__', '__minimum_numpy_version__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '__version__', '_check_numpy', '_get_test_runner', '_init_log', '_initialize_astropy', '_teardown_log', 'config', 'constants', 'coordinates', 'cosmology', 'cython_version', 'extern', 'find_api_page', 'io', 'log', 'logger', 'logging', 'online_docs_root', 'table', 'test', 'time', 'units', 'utils', 'version', 'version_helpers', 'wcs']
```

The above output shows that the built-in functions of astropy that you mentioned in your question: cosmology, time and units have all been successfully imported.

The following Python code<sup>**1**</sup> is a simple test to check if the cosmology and units built-in functions of astropy are working correctly. From IDLE3 run the following commands:

```
from astropy.cosmology import WMAP9 as cosmo
H0 = cosmo.H(0)
H0.value, H0.unit
```

The expected output is:

```
(69.32, Unit("km / (Mpc s)"))
```

<sup>**1**</sup><sub>Source: [Cosmological Calculations (astropy.cosmology)](http://astropy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cosmology/)</sub>

Comment: I run the command you said but it results: **python3-astropy is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 17 not upgraded.**
Then I run **sudo apt-get upgrade python3-astropy** this run the upgrade but... (cont..)

Comment: (cont)... still when I import astropy on IDLE and checked dir (astropy) it gives **['ConfigurationItem', 'UNICODE_OUTPUT', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__githash__', '__loader__', '__minimum_numpy_version__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '__version__', '_check_numpy', '_get_test_runner', '_init_log', '_initialize_astropy', '_teardown_log', 'config', 'cython_version', 'extern', 'find_api_page', 'log', 'logger', 'logging', 'online_docs_root', 'test', 'utils', 'version', 'version_helpers']**

NO MENTIONED LIBRARY

Comment: @user3269913 Sorry, I left out a line of code. I edited the missing line back in, and it works now.

Comment: do you mean **sudo apt-get install python3-astropy**? It doesn't work in the manner I want and If it doesn't work all other are useless. :(

Comment: No, the missing line I added is the third line of code, the line that says `from astropy.cosmology import WMAP9 as cosmo`. It comes immediately before the line that says `dir(astropy)`.